# How to get each value from set after storing set in sharedpreference

Tags: android, set, sharedpreferences

I am using this code for string array of string values in shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            "browser_opened_urls", 0);
    Set<String> urls = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Browser.mainWebViewFlipper.getChildCount(); i++) {
        WebView webview = (WebView) Browser.mainWebViewFlipper
                .getChildAt(i);
        urls.add(webview.getUrl());
    }
    preferences.edit().putStringSet("URLs", urls).commit();
```

But i am not getting how to get the values when retrieving set from shared preferences. Can anyone help ?

This is my code when i am getting set.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("browser_opened_urls", 0);
Set<String> urls = preferences.getStringSet("URLs", null);
```

Now can anyone tell me how to get each stored value from "urls" ?

Ok i found answer myself.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("browser_opened_urls", 0);
Set<String> urls = preferences.getStringSet("URLs", null);
if (urls != null) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = urls.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
         String url = iterator.next();
    }
```

Comment: where do you getting the values?

Comment: Try this way : String url = preferences .getString("URLs", ""); and also check out this for more details : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Use getString method to retrieve the data from sharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [android api reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).
Use method:- 
`getStringSet(String key, Set<String> defValues)`

The solution to your question is
 `SharedPreferences prefs=preferences.getStringSet(String URLs, Set<String> urls);` 
This is assuming you want to store in a new object for retrieving the old set